# Displaying the output of a looped full adder in System Verilog

Tags: system-verilog

I'm trying to debug whether or not my ripple adder code works by outputting the sum of the loop/adder to the console, however all that is output is "x". This code has worked in similar places without a for loop, so I'm curious as to why it doesn't seem to work here.

This is my code:

```
  module ripple_adder #(parameter W = 4) 
  (input logic [4-1:0] a,b,
   input logic cin,
   output logic [4-1:0] c,
   output logic cout);

  assign a = 4'b0011;
  assign b = 4'b1001;

  logic [4:0] h;
  
  assign h[0] = cin;
  assign cout = h[4];   
  genvar i;

  
  generate 
    for(i=0; i<4; i=i+1) begin: a_forloop
        fulladder Ai(a[i],b[i],h[i],c[i],h[i+1]); 
    end
  endgenerate
  
  initial begin
  #1
  
    $display("c = %d", c);
  end

  endmodule
```

Is it possible to make this work? Or is this something with the `generate` block that makes it not possible to use `display` here?

Comment: Show us a [complete executable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @dave_59 Fixed the question, didn't realise I didn't copy my whole code.

Comment: you forgot to initialize `h[0]`. As  a result the `x` from it gets propagated to all satges of the adder. It should be `0` when `i` is 0.

Comment: Variables of type bit default to 0.  Useful in a testbench, does not work in RTL.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, you need to initialize `h` input at time 0. So, something like the following should work:

```
   for(i=0; i<4; i=i+1) begin: a_forloop
        if (i == 0)
           fulladder Ai(a[i],b[i],  1'b0,c[i],h[i]); 
        else
           fulladder Ai(a[i],b[i],h[i-1],c[i],h[i]); 
    end
```